# Semicolon usage in this sentence

Tags: semicolons

Was the semi-colon used correctly in this sentence?

> In my opinion, anyone can apply this mindset to change unhealthy habits into good ones; and in return, turn his or her life around.

Answer (score 16):

The semicolon in the sentence in question does not connect two independent clauses, so it is used in the wrong place.

Semicolons help us connect closely related ideas when a style mark stronger than a comma is needed.

- http://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html

> **Rules for Using Semicolons**
>
> 1. A semicolon is most commonly used to link (in a single sentence) two independent clauses that are closely related in thought.
>
>    When a semicolon is used to join two or more ideas (parts) in a sentence, those ideas are then given equal position or rank.
>
>    > Some people write with a word processor; others write with a pen or pencil.
> 2. Use a semicolon between two independent clauses that are connected by conjunctive adverbs or transitional phrases.
>
>    > But however they choose to write, people are allowed to make their own decisions; as a result, many people swear by their writing methods.
> 3. Use a semicolon between items in a list or series if any of the items contain commas.
>
>    > There are basically two ways to write: with a pen or pencil, which is inexpensive and easily accessible; or by computer and printer, which is more expensive but quick and neat.
> 4. Use a semicolon between independent clauses joined by a coordinating conjunction if the clauses are already punctuated with commas or if the clauses are lengthy.
>
>    > Some people write with a word processor, typewriter, or a computer; but others, for different reasons, choose to write with a pen or pencil.
>
> **Avoid using a comma when a semicolon is needed:**
>
> Incorrect: The cow is brown, it is also old.
> Correct: The cow is brown; it is also old.

Answer (score 6):

The semicolon is not used correctly. *The Chicago Manual of Style* explains (emphasis mine) —

> In regular prose, a semicolon is most commonly used between *two independent clauses not joined by a conjunction* to signal a closer connection between them than a period would.

The sentence does not contain two independent clauses. It has a single, main clause,

```
anyone can apply this mindset . . .
```

followed by two subordinate clauses,

```
to change habits . . .
```

and

```
to turn . . . life . . . around.
```

The sentence *does* have a *conjunction*. (Usually, when you see a conjunction used properly, it's a clue that the sentence may not be a good candidate for the use of a semicolon.)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: The semicolon should be changed to a comma.

Generally, a comma is used to join clauses (phrases) with a connector such as the word 'and' ([Connector List](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-semicolons?page=3)). This is the reason the original question should have a comma where the semicolon currently is.

However, with longer, more complex clauses that each need commas of their own, a semicolon is acceptable to separate the two main clauses ([Complex Clauses](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-semicolons?page=1)). While the original question is complex the words *"and in return, turn his or her life around"* is a sentence fragment and as such is a subordinate clause. To use a semicolon as placed, this section of the sentence would have be be worded something like *"in return, they can turn their life around."*

Comment: As a native speaker I have to disagree. I'd find it acceptable in a list with at least three items, at least one of which has a comma, but this usage definitely feels wrong.

Comment: While this may be a complex clause, it is still a dependent clause so the semicolon is incorrect. As the source you quoted specifies, they have to be complex independent clauses to use a semicolon.